# Regarding ajaxStart/ajaxStop jquery

Tags: jquery

i have seen that ajaxStart/ajaxStop always used against a `DIV`. Consider the following:

```
$("#lbl_ajaxInProgress").ajaxStart(function() {
    // update labels
    $(this).text('Yes');
});

$("#lbl_ajaxInProgress").ajaxStop(function() {
    // update labels
    $(this).text('No');
});
```

Why do we need to bind ajaxstart/stop against a `div`?
can't we use like

```
$ajaxStart(function() {
    // update labels
    $(this).text('Yes');
});

$ajaxStop(function() {
    // update labels
    $(this).text('No');
});
```

That when ajax request will be made then ajaxStart function will be invoked and ajaxStop will be invoked when ajax request completed. Please elaborate on this requirement.

---

after changing bit now it is wokking here the working version

```
$("#imgHolder").ajaxStart(function () {
        $(document).ajaxStart(function () {
            $('div#content').block({
                message: '<table><tr><td><img  src="../images/ajax-loader.gif" border="0"/></td><td><h3>Processing...</h3></td></tr><table>',
                css: { border: '1px solid #a00' }
            });

            $('#imgHolder').empty();
            $("#btnPrint").hide();
        });

        $("#imgHolder").ajaxStop(function () {
        $(document).ajaxStop(function () {
            $("#btnPrint").show();
            $('div#content').unblock();
        });
```

Comment: you can use `beforeSend` and `complete` in [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe a stupid question, but why do you use `ajaxStart` and `ajaxStop` when you can do the start stuff right before your `.ajax(` call and the stop when the function succeeds or fails (succes, error)

```
/* ajaxStart stuff here */
$('div#content').block({
   message: '<table><tr><td><img  src="../images/ajax-loader.gif" border="0"/></td><td><h3>Processing...</h3></td></tr><table>',
   css: { border: '1px solid #a00' }
});
$('#imgHolder').empty();
$("#btnPrint").hide();
/* end start */
$.ajax({ 
    type: "POST", 
    url:  "myAjax.asmx/Sample",        
    data: dataString, 
    cache: false, 
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
    dataType: "json", 
    success: function (msg) {
        $("#btnPrint").show();
        $('div#content').unblock();
    },
    error:function(xhr,err){
        $('div#content').fadeOut();
        alert("readyState: " + xhr.readyState + "\nstatus: " + xhr.status);
        alert("responseText: " + xhr.responseText);
    }
});
```

Then you do not have the `<div>` requirement.